# How to make a navbar in a fragment android studio

Tags: java, android, fragment, navbar, tablayout

I was running into some trouble making a navbar in a fragment that was loaded by a different navbar.

Basically trying to solve the problem of having a menu in a fragment that was accessed by a navbar.

The easiest thing turned out to be creating a tablayout in the fragment. Here's the tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIKdHeOjYNw

Here's the basic code:

**Main Fragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    TabLayout tabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = root.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerHomeScreen);
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {


    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return new HomeScreenMembership();
            case 1 :
                return new HomeScreenCreatedClubs();
            default :
                return new HomeScreenMembership();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**Main Fragment XMl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/membership_tab" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/created_clubs_tab" />


    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerHomeScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**One of the Fragments For One Of the Tabs**
(the rest were almost identical)

```
package com.freedommuskrats.clubbub.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.freedommuskrats.clubbub.R;


public class HomeScreenCreatedClubs extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen_created_clubs, container, false);
    }
}
```

**XML for that fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeScreenCreatedClubs">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Created" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well and I'm even thinking of ditching the navbar in the future because it was so much more complex.